# Trouble cutting to a destination

Tags: vba, excel

Trying simply to cut from one range and paste it to another neatly, rather than using paste etc. This is what I have:

```
Sub Format_Excel_Confirm(clientName As String, newWB As Workbook)

lRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2", "B" & lRow).Cut(Range("AF2", "AF" & lRow))
```

and it's failing due to:

> "Cut method of Range class failed" error.

Comment: Add `Call` at the start of the line or get rid of the parenthesis after the `.Cut`

Comment: Perfect thank you.  I just removed the parentheses.  That's rather annoying the way that works you would think a directive would need to be enclosed.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, if you use **parenthesis around your arguments**, it means that you will **assign the value** of the line to a variable.

You can cancel the *return* of the line with a `Call` on the start of your line

Or just get rid of the parenthesis around your arguments!

---

So `Range("B2", "B" & lRow).Cut(Range("AF2", "AF" & lRow))` should be :

```
Call Range("B2", "B" & lRow).Cut(Range("AF2", "AF" & lRow))
'Or
Range("B2", "B" & lRow).Cut Range("AF2", "AF" & lRow)
```